# Finding a seven-digit number with all of its prime factors less than 20?

Tags: number-theory, factorization

How can I find a seven-digit number with all of its prime factors less than 20?

I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: It would depend on where one lost it..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not specific to Mathematica software.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Let's suppose you didn't lose it. Then find it  ad absurdum.

Comment: In case someone visits this (badly asked) closed question, it seems to be about [smooth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number). A small code, yet too big for this marginal comment, shows there are 11447 seven-digit numbers composed of only primes less than 20. The smallest is 1000000, the largest is 9997020.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the 8th prime is less than 20 (`Prime[8]` = 19), then the product of all primes up to and including that one is:

```
Times @@ Prime[Range[8]]
```

(*
9699690
*)

You can list those primes:

```
Prime[Range[8]]
```

You can answer the generalized problem from the below figure, e.g., How many distinct, sequential, smallest prime factors are needed to get a number greater than $10^{18}$?

```
ListLogPlot[Table[{i, Times @@ Prime[Range[i]]}, {i, 1, 20}],
 AxesLabel -> {Text[
    Style["number of\n sequential prime\n factors of \!\(\*
StyleBox[\"x\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", 18]], Text[Style["\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"x\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", 18]]},
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer since it even works for distinct primes. Of course, if the primes can repeat, 2^20 gets my vote.

Comment: Well sure... $2^{20}$.